# In tensorflow, Do I have to set something special to ignore zero padding value when training? Or is it automatic?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, zero-padding

I want to train sequence data to Rnn base model with some zero paddings using tensorflow.

And I want model to ignore 0 values when training.

Do I have to set parameters to do that? or Does model automatically ignore zeros?

Thanks,,

Answer (score 1):

It is not automatic, You should introduce `Masking` to achieve this. It means how layers are able to know when to ignore certain timesteps in sequence inputs.

You can introduce it in three ways

- You can add a `tf.keras.layers.Masking` layer
- You can configure a `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` layer with `mask_zero=True`
- You can pass a `mask` argument [manually when calling layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) that support this argument

For more information you can refer [Masking and padding with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding) guide.